# using Enum to build locator for selenium test

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I come out one question about selenium web test. Since all elements require their own xpath or css selector to be action by selenium webdriver.
I have tried to use python Enum and create something like

```
file: elementEnum.py
from enum import Enum

class PageA(Enum):
    pElementA = '//div[{}]'
    pElementB = '//a[.="{}"]'
    pElementC = '//div[@class={}]'

class PageB(Enum):
    pElementA = '//button[.="{}""]'
    pElementB = '//table/tr[{}]/td[{}]'
```

but it turns out lots of time I require to build the string in python format function and it does not see pythonoic.

```
from elementEnum import *
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="aaaaaa"]/{}'.format((PageA.pElementA.value).format(1)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('{}/{}'.format(PageA.pElementA.value).format(1), PageA.pElementB.value.format(2)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('{}/{}'.format(PageB.pElementB.value).format(1, 3), PageA.pElementA.value.format(2)))
```

What is the best way for me to list out all corresponse element and their locator.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the

EC.visibility_of_element_located to locate the element

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

sample code :

```
class SeleniumBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def open(self,URL):
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def driverURLChange(self,URL):  
        print("change URL" + URL)
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def currentUrl(self):
        print("URL   " +  self.driver.current_url)
        return self.driver.current_url
    def switchNewWindow(self):
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
        return self.driver.title
    def locateElement(self, loc):
        try:
            print(loc)
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(loc))
            return element
        except:
            print ("cannot find {0} element".format(loc))
        return None
```

and you could

```
password_loc =(By.NAME,'password')
webdriver = SeleniumBaseClass(driver)
webdriver.locateElement(password_loc )
```

this could you pass the tuple to locate the element